# Is there a workaround for error: "Could not write image: Too many open files"?

Tags: blend-files, error

I'm on windows 10, version 2.79 of blender. I've rendered a small (<1080p) image and when I attempt to save it it fails with error:

Could not write image: Too many open files.

I have tried saving by using Image>Save As Image(F3) as well as rendering a one-frame animation. This error does not occur with any smaller projects. But this project contains 1,275 textures. I have tested up to 485 textures without issues. Deleting and removing a few of these textures doesn't seem to make a difference. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Cheers!

Message me if a blend file is necessary to solve this.

Comment: That is an insane amount of textures. Like actually ridiculous. Is there no way to combine them?

Comment: They are auto-imported from a game's data files. Not a whole lot I can do about it.

Comment: are they actually all being used in the scene? if some are part of one or many materials but aren't actually being used you can shift-click the delete icon to get rid of them permanently from your project. once you close blender and open it back up they will be gone for good...  or you could try to screenshot the rendered image and save it that way (if it's bigger than your screen then take a bunch of screenshots and stitch them together in you favorite image editor).

Comment: Thanks for the response Sebastián. I may end up screen capturing and stitching. If I render a scene, then close and reopen blender without saving the render, I believe the image is lost. I am curious why blender is unable to save. The image clearly exists on ram and blender has no problem displaying it on my screen. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaroud that I have developed is as follows.

1. Render my scene.
2. View>Toggle Fullscreen Area
3. View>View Fit
4. Zoom in to a level where the pixels in the image are larger than the pixels of your display.
5. Take screen captures of each part of the image. (On Windows, Shipping Tool works well)
6. Stitch these together in an image editing software. I used Photomerge in Photoshop Elements.
7. Remove the border using a pixel color select tool and crop (in Photoshop Elements, the magic wand works well)
8. Resize your image to the original desired resolution. This is also an opportunity to touch up those nasty fireflies.
9. Save and share.

I hope this helps.